# GPU cuda code for array processing, abstract

Tags: arrays, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have an array of several millions of integer values(input). I would like to perform function `F(input[x])` on them individually and separately, using GPU, nvidia gtx 780ti or gtx 980, then have the results array (output) back in main memory, each output element `output[x]` corresponding to input array element `input[x]`. `F()` does not contain any floating point calculations.

How do i organize such a task of this size array(millions of elements) properly for gpu ?

Im looking for a proper GPU substitute to this :

`for (int x=0; x<5000000; x++)`

`output[x] = F(input[x])`;

Comment: Have a look at [thrust::transform](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#ga281b2e453bfa53807eda1d71614fb504)

Comment: You can also write a trivial CUDA kernel to do this.  This is probably the easiest of all problems to "organize" on the GPU.  Take a look at the CUDA vector Add sample code.  That is `output[x] = F(input1[x], input2[x])`, but it is a trivial matter to simplify it further to what you are asking about.

Comment: @m.s. I think this one should be pretty easy to answer.  If you want to provide an answer I would upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to provide an answer to this question, I convert the comments into this answer:

Your use case is very easily implemented in CUDA.
A very beginner-friendly way to do this is using [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct F
{
     __device__
     int operator()(int value) const
     {
         // just a dummy function
         return value*value;
     }
};

int main()
{
     const int N = 10;
     thrust::device_vector<int> input(N);
     // filling the input with dummy values
     thrust::sequence(input.begin(), input.end());
     thrust::device_vector<int> output(N);
     thrust::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), F());
     thrust::copy(output.begin(), output.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

     return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this code yields:

```
$ nvcc transform.cu && ./a.out

0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

Of course, you can also write a very simple, plain CUDA kernel to accomplish this task as Robert suggested.